# Why is currentQuestion undefined?

Tags: knockout.js

I want to display only the current question choices. I have set currentQuestion in the ViewModel to the first element in the array.
Yet it is undefined.
I installed the knockout context chrome plugin and all other variables seem to be set correctly. I don't know why currentQuestion has a value of undefined.
Thanks

```
<div id="quiz-container">
 <form action="">
    <div data-bind="with: currentQuestion">
        <h3 data-bind="text: question"></h3>

        <div data-bind="foreach: choices">

            <input type="radio" data-bind="checkedValue: $data, checked: $parent.selectedAnswer" />
            <span data-bind="text: $data">choice</span>

        </div>
        <div>
            <button data-bind="click: $parent.previousQuestion">Previous</button>
            <button data-bind="click: $parent.nextQuestion">Next</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div><input type="submit"/></div>
</form>
</div>
<script src="js/jQuery.js"></script>
```

```
function Question( data ) {
var self = this;
self.question = data.question;
self.choices = ko.observableArray( [] );
data.choices.forEach( function ( c ) {
    self.choices.push( c );
} );
self.answer = data.answer;
};

function QuizViewModel() {

var self = this;

self.questionList = ko.observableArray( [] );

// Load initial state from server, convert it to Question instances, then populate self.questions
$.getJSON( "js/questions.json", function ( allData ) {
    var mappedQuestions = $.map( allData, function ( item ) {
        return new Question( item )
    } );
    self.questionList( mappedQuestions );
} );

self.currentQuestion = ko.observable(self.questionList()[0]);

this.previousQuestion = function () {
    var index = self.questionList().indexOf( self.currentQuestion );
    self.currentQuestion( self.questionList()[index - 1] );
};

this.nextQuestion = function () {
    var index = self.questionList().indexOf( self.currentQuestion );
    self.currentQuestion( self.questionList()[index + 1] );
};

};

ko.applyBindings( new QuizViewModel() );
```

Comment: check that self.questionList()[index-1] is having right value ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because it's being set at the time the `QuizViewModel` is instantiated, whilst the questions are got asynchronously.  Instead, just create an observable, and set it when the async call returns:

```
$.getJSON( "js/questions.json", function ( allData ) {
    var mappedQuestions = $.map( allData, function ( item ) {
        return new Question( item )
    } );
    self.questionList( mappedQuestions );

    //set current question when the async call returns
    self.currentQuestion(self.questionList()[0]);
} );

//initialise as observable
self.currentQuestion = ko.observable();
```

Comment: this is issue for very first time load..but when you next/previous it should work

Comment: not if it's not been initalised properly - the `indexOf` call will always return -1, so previous wouldn't work (at least until you've clicked next), but next would be ok.  Either way - it needs to be initialised correctly _after_ the questions have been loaded.  You can't initialise it to a member of an array that hasn't been populated yet.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply! that makes sense. It now is set to the first question object. However the binding doesn't seem to work, so nothing is displayed. If I replace `with: currentQuestion` by `with questionList()[0]`, it does display correctly. Any suggestions?

Comment: @Paul Did you put `self.currentQuestion(self.questionList()[0]);` in your async return as in my answer, or copy the original `self.currentQuestion = ko.observable(self.questionList()[0]);`?  If you did the latter, you're actually assigning a new observable to it, whilst the html is bound to the original one with no value.

Comment: oops, facepalm, I had the wrong syntax in the assignment inside the ajax call. Thanks James - you're awesome :)

Comment: @paul I wouldn't go that far, we've all been there :)